# Webbrowser unable to perform search and authentication

Tags: internet-explorer

Greeting everyone. Thank you for your time to read my question. I am hoping that the descrption of the issue I put below actually make sense. I have tried to google around many sites but can't seem to find issues that match mine.

Problem happens mainly on websites where searching/query to database is performed, such as searching an automobile database in car sale website. Typically what happen is, when select all criteria for the search and start searching, the webbrowser doesn't seem to load, it is not freezing, but just porgress bar moving very slowly and eventually after long time it shows all sort of errors (such as pg can't be displayed, server busy etc.)...Similar issue also happen on websites that require authentication, especially hotmail, after click on login, the progress bar start loading extrememly slow and eventually failed. Recently, same problem also happens when trying to post a thread

Please allow me to brief the troubleshooting i have done so far:
1. Tried all different webbrowser, IE7, fairfox, Chrome etc
2. Problem happened 2 months after PC was reformatted.
3. Checked security setting in browser, all default
4. PC is installed with up to date Norton Antivirus and Firewall
5. System drive has been defragmented
6. PC generally works fine with little issue apart from this one

I would really appreciate any suggestion/advise

Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Firefox, and install the HttpFox plugin.  Open it up and click "Start".  Then you will see every HTTP request you make, and how long it takes to respond.  You may at least get a clue as to which request(s) is/are causing the problem?